# For each prefix of length 'i' find out if there are exactly two numbers that occur equal number of times

Tags: python

Дан массив целых чисел 'a' длины 'n'. Для каждого префикса длины i(1<= i >= n) выясните, существуют ли ровно два числа, которые встречаются одинаковое количество раз.
Префикс массива длины 'i' - это первые 'i' элементов массива.

Я просмотрел примеры и увидел, что первый ответ всегда будет NO (потому что есть только одно число), третий ответ всегда будет NO.

| In | Out |
| --- | --- |
| 5 1 2 1 2 3 | NO YES NO YES YES |

Мой код(достаточно простой), но он не проходит тесты из-за ограничения по времени:

```py
from collections import Counter
_,a=int(input()),list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
    Uniq=Counter(a[:i])
    numberofUniq=list(Uniq.values())
    wasTwo=False
    wasTwo = True if 2 in Counter(numberofUniq).values() else False
    print('YES' if wasTwo else 'NO')
```

Помогите мне оптимизировать код пожалуйста

Comment: use `collections.Counter`, `.values()`, `set()` and `len()`

Comment: добавь описание как работает твой алгоритм